# Is the ConstraintLayout the new standard?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

My question is about the `ConstraintLayout` because since **Android Studio 2.3**, when I want to create a new `Layout`, the default `Layout` in my xml file is the `ConstraintLayout`.

Is the `ConstraintLayout` the new standard ?

What about the others layouts (`LinearLayout`, `GridLayout`, `RelativeLayout`,...) ? Will they be depreciated ? Do I have to Convert all my layout using the converting tool ?

What is the best practice? Use as much as possible the `ConstraintLayout` ?

This is a bit confusing because I don't like to use the visual editor and it's a quite difficult to do `ConstraintLayout` using the code editor.

Comment: No it is not. Use whatever you prefer.

Comment: `Is the ConstraintLayout the new standard?` **No**. It's only the new ConstraintLayout. Nothing less, nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I want to create a new Layout, the default Layout in my xml file is the ConstraintLayout

Whether or not a `ConstraintLayout` is created depends entirely on what templates you are using.

> Is the ConstraintLayout the new standard ?

It is what many of the Android Studio 2.3 templates use. Those templates are merely examples used a starting point by some developers. Those templates differ on older versions of Android Studio and most likely will change again in the future.

> What about the others layouts (LinearLayout, GridLayout, RelativeLayout,...) ? Will they be depreciated ?

That is very unlikely.

> Do I have to Convert all my layout using the converting tool ?

No.

> What is the best practice? Use as much as possible the ConstraintLayout ?

Use what works for you. Consider `ConstraintLayout` as a candidate, but do not feel obligated to use it. In particular places where you determine that layout performance is critical (e.g., scrolling lists), if you determine that your existing approach is not performing well, consider testing `ConstraintLayout` to see if it helps (it may or it may not). Also note that `ConstraintLayout` itself does not handle all scenarios — for example, I have yet to see a working means of implementing a `TableLayout` structure (with automatic column sizing) using a `ConstraintLayout`.